# Get access to enclosing object in Jackson deserializer

Tags: java, json, jackson, deserialization, json-deserialization

(Jackson 2.9.9)
I have two classes:

```
public final class Parent {
  private final String parentName;
  private final Child child;

  /*serialization constructor and stuff*/
}

public final class Child {
  private final String someField;

  /*serialization constructor and stuff*/
}
```

and a custom deserializer for Child registered:

```
public final class ChildCustomDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Child> {
 private final List<String> parentNames;

 public @NotNull T deserialize(@NotNull JsonParser parser, @NotNull DeserializationContext ctxt) {
   /*deserialization logic here*/
   //any way to refer Parent from here to fill parent names?
 }
}
```

Is there any way I can get any of the parent info inside `deserialize` method?

Comment: Is `Parent` meant to be a superclass of `Child`? What do you mean _get any of the parent info_? Use the available members in `Parent`.

Comment: Nope, sorry for the ambigious naming. `Parent` here  means that  JSON object i try to deserialize contains some of the `Child` objects. What I'm trying to do is to get and access to the outer object while deserializing inner object. For example, a property `name` of the `Parent` or at least class name

Comment: Oh, so you have a `Parent` deserializer. While it's deserializing its child, you want the `Parent` to be passed down to the `ChildCustomDeserializer`?

Comment: For a `Parent` object, a default serializer is used, so there's no way i can do so. To be clear, may `Parent` be an abstract class, and I want to know which inheritor is using the `Child`

Comment: If you had a `ParentDeserializer`, you might be able to use `DesrializationContext` `setAttribute` and `getAttribute`. But this seems like a very weird way to do things. Can you share more about the overall goal?

Comment: Sure, an overall goal is, for each unique `Child`, collect all the `Parent` objects which refer to it. I tried to use `parser.getParserContext.getValue()` for this purposes, but it normally returns `null` for me.

Comment: Any way I can write custom deserializer for Parent like this? 
`context.setProperty("parent's name"); 
return //serialize as default?`

Comment: This seems like something you can do after the deserialization is done.

Comment: Well, thank you here, that's a nice idea, gonna do it this way unless I'll find a soultion I desire (due to performanse issues). Really appreciate it!